# Classpath differences when running from src/main and src/test

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jersey

I have two projects with Project-1 being dependent on Project-2

```
project-1  
           src/main/resources
           src/test/resources
           src/functional-test/resources

project-2
          src/main/resources/
          src/test/resources
```

Project-1 has a project dependency on project-2.

Project-1 is a web application and when I launch tomcat it finds applicationContext.xml from classpath and loads spring beans.

**Everything works fine If i start the tomcat server and hit the service through a browser but when i run the jersey tests application context doesn't load.** 
When I run tomcat it looks for application context in Project-1's src/main/resources/ and loads the beans
Project-1 applicationContext.xml refers xmls from Project-2 src/main/resources/ which use property files in project-2.

When i copy the contents of Project-1 src/main/resources into Project-1 src/test/resources and do the same for Project-2.This problem is fixed.
Now i get Error creating bean with name 'emf'
A xml file in Project-2 contains

```
    <bean id="emf" 
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">

          < bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        ...
        ...
     </bean>
```

How can it be that it is on the classpath when launching tomcat in which case entry point is src/main/java/ 
and It is not in classpath when running the JerseyTest in src/test/java

(It could have been the other way around if there was a testCompile dependency not available during normal run)
Classpath is of the Jvm .What has src/main or src/test got to do with it?**Is there a way to modify the Junit classpath (a jvm only) to include what it is when the vm was run from src/main?**

Comment: Try explicitly creating the app context and set it as a property `"contextConfig"`, with the ResourceConfig, kinda like seen [here](https://github.com/psamsotha/underdog-jersey-spring-example/blob/master/src/test/java/com/underdog/jersey/spring/example/test/GreetingResourceIntegrationTest.java#L27), but using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` instead (since you're using xml)

Comment: @peeskillet awesome! .That works though there were two more issues that I had to remove a needless spring-asm dependency coming through one of the projects.I think this is not a jersey-spring compatibility issue but issue with spring 3.1.2 present in build path. I also had to provide javax.el-api dependency.Not sure why was this not needed when running the tomcat and hitting the rest service but only when running the test.

Comment: Although i put xml and property files in src/test of respective Projects because they where not present in classpath when running from gradle.There could be a way to do that but I am still looking into the project hierarchies and many gradle files.This is good enough for me as I can specify the file to load from test